# Not using the base attribute when making DomSanitizer API calls?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I'm making a call using the DomSanitizer like this:

```
        this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url));
```

The `url` is complete URL to the SVG image being fetched.

Here's is an example:

```
      this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
        "fs",
        this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://github.com/fireflysemantics/images/blob/master/fsalpha/logo/fsalpha-logo-optimized.svg'));
```

However since `base` is set to another URL in `index.html`, the dom sanitizer URL is prefixed with it.

Is there a way to switch this off?

This is an article I wrote showing how it works without the `base` attribute added:

https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/angular-material-icon-from-github-hosted-svg-logo-d5c35b923d

And this is a stackblitz that shows that when the base attribute is added, the call to the absolute URL is prefixed with the base attribute, so the URL passed becomes broken:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-custom-icon-with-base?file=src/index.html

### Feature Request

Angular has a feature request WRT to this issue:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23139

## Angular Issue

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34645

## Screenshot of Bug

This is a screenshot of the stacktrace showing that the base URL is prefixed before the image URL:

[image]

Comment: Does the URL start with a protocol? `http://`

Comment: Yes all the resource URLs being used start with `'https://fireflysemantics.github.io/images/'`

Comment: This is the app making those calls: https://fsalpha-canary.fireflysemantics.com/

Comment: If you click on the console and look at the errors you'll see that the base attribute is prefixed onto the image URL.

Comment: So it looks like the Angular HttpClient is removing the `https://` part that is in the URL when the call is made.

Comment: Update the question to show how you're using the sanitized URL in the template.

Comment: Just added a real example.

Comment: Also added a link to a blog article I wrote demoing how to load SVG cross domain without the base attribute.  I modified the Stackblitz that shows what happens when the base attribute is added.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34645

Comment: I don't see any bug here. The stackblitz is missing closing head tag. This one is working without bug: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-custom-icon-with-base-zavkvw?file=src/index.html, image: https://imgur.com/v8QQS3R

Comment: Thanks - I may have goofed the demo - However the bug is there.  I'll attach a screenshot of the `fsalpha-canary` release of the effect I was seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug. There is no possible reason for the HttpClient to rewrite a URL which has a protocol.

Material icon registry doesn't mutate any of the URLs for icons. It doesn't really do anything special with the URL, and just defers loading to the HttpClient.

https://github.com/angular/components/blob/09dc4594259cf1d6b34a5a0893c0bccaa132c319/src/material/icon/icon-registry.ts#L595

I haven't been able to reproduce this, because it would require deploying an app to a domain like gh pages, but if you are seeing this happening then please open an issue on the Angular GitHub project and let them know.

The only answer that I can give you is to write a custom interceptor to fix the URL.

Here's a blog explaining how to use the interceptor to use a base URL. It's not a guide on how to fix your problem, but it's the closest thing that I could find.

http://www.projectcodify.com/angular-set-base-url-dynamically

Comment: Thanks!  Good observation!  I'll file another issue with Angular.  The medium blog and Stackblitz demo that I linked show the same behavior.  The medium article has a stackblitz that works without the base attribute.  I forked that and added the base attribute and it breaks the URL.

Comment: @Ole it's very strange. I've used base and HttpClient together without any trouble. It could be a edge case with the sanitizer, and I have a feeling this might be specific to an Angular version. Hopefully it's not a big deal and they fix it.

Comment: @Reactular I think you nailed it on the head.  There's really no reason to prefix and absolute URL, so hopefully it will be fixed fast.  Thanks again for the collaboration!